# How can I Insert date and time into input field via a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, date, time

I need a script that will insert the current date and time in an input field via a button click?  Can anyone refer me to a script?

I prefer jquery or ajax or javascript.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think he means html/javascript

Comment: I prefer jquery or ajax or javascript.

Comment: Javascript (technically ECMAScript) is a language; jQuery is a toolkit built on that language; AJAX is a technique, not a language or toolkit.  It's not really an X or Y or Z situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(
    function(){

        $('#time').click(function(){
                  var time = new Date();                
                  $('#time-holder').val(time.toDateString());  
        });

    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/28Wqq/).

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation:

```
<form>
  <input name="theDate" size="50">
  <input type="button" value="Insert date" onclick="
    this.form.theDate.value = new Date();
  ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
 $('#yourButtonId').click(function() {
       var now = new Date();
       $('#yourInputId').val(now.toDateString());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can use the Date object. To change the input's value when you click on a button, you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").onclick = function() {
     var date = new Date();
     document.getElementById("inputId").value = date.toString();
};
```

Or, if you only want to use part of the date or to format it another way, you can get the specific attributes of the object with functions like `date.getDate()`, `date.getFullYear()`, etc., and replace `date.toString()` with whatever format you want there. There's a full list of the Date object's methods at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Please don't reference [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/), either reference [ECMA-262](http://es5.github.com/) or, if examples are needed, a relevant part of the [JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) at MDN. Note that MDN is for JavaScript, which has many extensions to standard ECMAScript but also has links to relevant standards where applicable.

Comment: To add to RobG's comment, w3schools often has incomplete or outright incorrect information, and bad examples. Rob's link to w3fools.com explains more.